# How to set value to a text input that is invisible in webdriver.io?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, cucumber, cucumberjs

Using `browser.setValue(theXpathOfTheElement, 4242424242424242);` in a iFrame element returns :

```
An element command could not be completed because the element is in an invalid state
```

I did try to do the fallowing to make the frame focused:

```
browser.waitForVisible('//iframe[@id="myFrameId"]', 6000);
browser.frame('myFrameId');
```

but i get the same result. Am i doing the context switch correctly? Because that visually the field is visible and it is editable by using th keyboard input.

Comment: Selenium doesn't like to interact with things it can't see. It's interactions are based on what an actual user could do.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the wait time for waitForVisible and test it in this way

`browser.waitForVisible('iframe[id="yourIframeId"]');
 var my_frame = $('iframe[id="yourIframeId"]').value;
 browser.frame(my_frame);`

Then rest of the test on iframe element